# Translation of number into strings

Tags: c++, c

I would like to know whether there is a way in which we can print the number alphabetically i.e
`123` should be printed as `one two three`.

The only condition is that we should not reverse the number and we should not use array.

I only know these two ways:

- "Reverse the number", that is, taking the last digit and cutting it off. For each cut-off digit, one can use an array to look up the correct string.
- using `switch` and a lot of `case`s

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand why reversing it would help at all, and you don't need an array to loop through it. Seems like `std::transform` with a switch is what you really want if you have it in a string or something.

Comment: So you want to "translate" digits into strings?

Comment: i meant using array we can enter the number as a string and we can use switch case for(case s[i])

Comment: Study modulo arithmetic (the remainder from division).  It's messier (and slower) left-to-right but completely doable.

Comment: @chris: reversing comes from the simple arithmetic of `digit = number % 10; number /= 10`. Extracting the digits in the "correct" order is a bit trickier.

Comment: Concerning the limitation "no array", use a map or vector instead ;-)

Comment: Well, a string isn't an array, so if you can't make your life easier by using that, it's worth a mention.

Comment: Consider that you could write an algorithm that just did right-to-left, but did it repeatedly, and only printed the left-most as-yet-unprinted digit with each iteration.

Comment: @chris: i meant a character array....

Comment: (Of course you could also use recursion, which would be a bit of a "cheat" -- substituting the call stack for an array.)

Comment: @BipinBaburaj, If it's just a plain array that's not allowed, use `std::to_string` and then `std::transform` on that. It might not be the most efficient way, but it's pretty clear.

Comment: @chris - In C a string certainly *is* an array.

Comment: @HotLicks, Oh, sorry, I didn't even notice the C tag. If it's tagged C++, I assume C++.

Comment: @Bipin: Please choose either C or C++. If you're using C, you clearly do not want a C++ solution and if you're using C++, you clearly would want a C++ solution.

Comment: Seems to me it would be "cheating" to use a map or a vector or a C++ string or any other array-like object.

Comment: (And I think it behooves us to let the OP write his own code, vs doing his homework for him.  Just help -- don't do his work.)

Comment: The constraints are unclear. What do you mean by "we shouldn't reverse the number"? Does this mean that you must not process a more significant digit before a less significant one? Does this solution have to be portable? On the same topic, is using integer to string conversion functions allowed (and if so, how do you guarantee they are not "reversing the number" in the underlying implementation)?

Comment: I disagree with the close (or "put on hold" or whatever). "Not reversing" the number may not be the best formulation, but it's rather obvious that cutting of the least significant digit is not allowed. This question also includes an example of "input & expected output".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily the easiest route, but you can make a function, say `DigitToWord` which will take a digit 0, 1, 2, ...etc to its word with a switch statement. Then I recommend using a for loop over the number, continuously dividing by 10 and taking the mod for the loop:

```
int num; //my number i want to print
int div = pow(10, (int)log10(num)); //find the largest power of 10 smaller than num
while(num > 0) {
  int remainder = num%div;
  int digit = num/div;
  DigitToWord();
  num = remainder;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for hundreds place:

```
int hundreds = my_num / 100 //Needs "/", NOT "%"
if(hundreds == 0)
  cout << "zero";
else if(hundreds == 1)
  cout << "one";
//repeat for 2-9
```

This process could be tweaked to do the other digits as well. It is also worth mentioning that the if/else block a) could be done with a switch/case if preferred, and b) could pretty easily be made into a separate function to avoid having to repeat the block of code over and over, I just wrote out as much as I did for clarity's sake. Note that this assumes the number you're "translating" is an integer. With integers the "/" operator will return the full quotient WITHOUT the remainder, e.g. 123 / 100 = 1, not 1.23